# move cursor for edittext inside a scrollview

Tags: android, cursor, android-edittext, horizontalscrollview

I have an edit text that I need within a scrollview. Before I added a scrollview that wrapped the edittext, I was able to touch on the edit text box to move the cursor, and I could long press it to get the select options.  Now that I have the edit text within a scrollview, I am not able to click on the text and move the cursor, or long press to get the select options. Here is the xml I am using:

```
        <HorizontalScrollView 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        >

        <RelativeLayout 
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingRight="10dp">    
            <EditText
                 android:id="@+id/output"
                 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                 android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                 android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                 android:lines="1"
                 android:textSize="25dp"
                 android:text=""
                 android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                 android:background="@android:color/white" />

            <ImageView android:id="@+id/animated_output"
                android:layout_width="28dp"
                android:layout_height="25dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="9dp"

                android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/output"
                android:background="@color/transparent"/>


        </RelativeLayout> 

    </HorizontalScrollView>
```

Any idea why this may be?

Comment: Do you know if your ListView receives the event before your EditText is getting it? Can you dispatch the TouchEvent to your EditText?